# How to automatically switch to camera view after entering preview mode

Tags: game-engine

I'm making a small game in BGE and I have met a problem. I want this game to be played from a camera's view. But I have no idea on how to  **automatically** switch to camera view as soon as I enter preview mode. How do I do this? Is this even possible?

I really don't want to manually(<kbd>Numpad0</kbd>) switch to camera view when I go into preview mode.

Answer (score 2):

**WARNING:** If you are a 100% python person, and hate my answer already, leave now, because, yes, we are using logic bricks.

You will need a "Scene" logic brick, on the "set camera" mode. Specify the camera and rig this to an "Always" sensor.

[image]

This works in a pinch, but it gives some *extremely* strange perspective depths, and I wouldn't recommend using it for this reason. The real way is to hit <kbd>Num0</kbd> *every time*. Exhausting, I know.

*Note: after further testing, it would appear that the weirdo bug is gone! :D I could be incorrect, but this would make this a valid method in releases 2.77-later at least. Happy blending.*

Comment: well considering i've only spent like 3 hours on bge before and i've only done python outside of blender i couldn't care less if it has no python.